# Dynamic Add, Edit & Delete row in Table in Js

Tags: javascript

While i click the Add Row button it showing error. I want to append a new 'tr' of every time i click add row button. the each td must contain, checkbox, firstname, lastname, email, mobile edit & save.

1. i want to save the values if i click save button..
2. and edit button to edit the fields.
3. Checkbox is to select the multiple rows and delete the entire row.

Can someone please help me to do this.. thanks in advance.

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
document.body.appendChild(form);

var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute("id","myTable");
form.appendChild(table);

var btnClick = document.createElement('button');
btnClick.setAttribute('onclick','addTable()');
btnClick.innerHTML = "Add Row";
form.appendChild(btnClick);

var btnSave = document.createElement('button');
btnSave.innerHTML = "Save";

var btnDelete = document.createElement('button');
btnDelete.innerHTML = "Delete";

var btnEdit = document.createElement('button');
btnEdit.innerHTML = "Edit";

var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = "checkbox";

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = "text";
input.placeholder = "Firstname";

var input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.type = "text";
input1.placeholder = "Lastname";

var input2 = document.createElement('input');
input2.type = "email";
input2.placeholder = "Email";

var input3 = document.createElement('input');
input3.type = "number";
input3.placeholder = "Number";

function addTable() {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(row);  
  var cell = document.createElement('td');  
  row.appendChild(cell);
  cell.appendChild(checkbox);
  cell.appendChild(input);
  cell.appendChild(input1);
  cell.appendChild(input2);
  cell.appendChild(input3);
  cell.appendChild(btnSave);
  cell.appendChild(btnEdit);
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajdknL72/)

Comment: Jquery would make this way easier

Comment: I would also recommend binding your event like this `btnClick.addEventListener("click",addTable);`

Answer (score 0):

First and most important thing to change is the tag you're using for your add row button. By using a button you're going to cause the form to submit each time you press it, thereby undoing your row add and any other page changes. Use an < input > tag with type button if you want the same look. You'll probably want to do the same with your save edit and delete buttons if you want the page to respond without reloading.

For everything else you're pretty much there. If I were you I would stop using setAttribute for everything. You can set the id and onclick of an element by a direct property set (ie table.id = "myTable";). I typically only use setAttribute for inline style when I want to set more than one property at once (ie table.setAttribute("style","border:2px solid;color:red;");

Here's my version of your code that works.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var addTable = function() {
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";

        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = "text";
        input.placeholder = "Firstname";

        var input1 = document.createElement('input');
        input1.type = "text";
        input1.placeholder = "Lastname";

        var input2 = document.createElement('input');
        input2.type = "email";
        input2.placeholder = "Email";

        var input3 = document.createElement('input');
        input3.type = "number";
        input3.placeholder = "Number";

        var btnSave = document.createElement('button');
        btnSave.innerHTML = "Save";

        var btnDelete = document.createElement('button');
        btnDelete.innerHTML = "Delete";

        var btnEdit = document.createElement('button');
        btnEdit.innerHTML = "Edit";

        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        table.appendChild(row);  
        addCell(row,checkbox);
        addCell(row,input);
        addCell(row,input1);
        addCell(row,input2);
        addCell(row,input3);
        addCell(row,btnSave);
        addCell(row,btnEdit);
        addCell(row,btnDelete);
      };

      var form = document.createElement('form');
      form.method = "post";
      document.body.appendChild(form);

      var table = document.createElement('table');
      table.id = "myTable";
      form.appendChild(table);

      var btnClick = document.createElement('input');
      btnClick.type = "button";
      btnClick.value = "Add Row";
      btnClick.onclick = addTable;
      form.appendChild(btnClick);
  };

  function addCell(row,elm){
      var cell = document.createElement('td');  
      row.appendChild(cell);
      cell.appendChild(elm);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Bro :) will try this.